# fckeditor 2.5 doesnot remove html tags while displaying

Tags: php, fckeditor

I have fckeditor 2.5 for my zencart site. The problem is when i try to add description for the products copied from notepad file even the html tags like paragraph and break tags gets displayed on my site.
Can anyone please help to solve this issue?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These wysiwyg editor like fckeditor escape html tags in normal mode. This is as designed. You have to add your html in **source** mode. In default fckeditor, **source** button is the first one.

Comment: Thanks Gagandeep for your answer. But I did not type the contents directly instead I copied it from a plain notepad file and saved. When checked on my site the paragraph and break tags were displayed as a text.

Comment: May be I miss understood. You are saying you have normal text content in your notepad means not html content. Right?

Answer (score 0):

check out [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php I think that would help with this part of your problem. I think you will need stripslashes later.